# How to set up default timestamp to char conversion in postgreSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql, timestamp

I'm using psql util with PostgreSQL 15 on macOS. I've create new database and I want all queries to it return timestamp columns in format "DD.MM.YYYY HH:MM:SS". I want all functions and procedures in certain database use this format. Maybe it is better to set up this format in every table separately, but I've not found examples for doing this. I'm trying to set up my database to convert in that way by default.

I've started with using the next commands:

```
CREATE DATABASE my_database
    TEMPLATE template0;

ALTER DATABASE my_database
    SET datestyle TO 'ISO, DMY';
```

restarting postgresql server and making new connection. I hope to achieve timestamp in format DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS at least, but I've got the next result:

[image]

There are ways to do it changing configuration files or environment variables, but I need to apply behaviour to one database and nothing else outside it.

Comment: You want "Datestyle": https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-OUTPUT you can set it on the database with ALTER DATABASE. All this is easily discoverable by searching the manuals - it is worth keeping them open in a tab for stuff like this.

Comment: My friend shared this link with me: https://www.vertica.com/docs/10.0.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Statements/SET/SETDATESTYLE.htm. It says: "Vertica ignores the order argument for date styles ISO and GERMAN." It seems Postgres do the same, so usihg German datestyle is the solution of my problem.

Comment: 1) You realize any client above the database is free to format the datetime as it sees fit, so the format you specify in Postgres may not 'stick' outside it. 2) The format is not going to change the calculations.

Comment: Yes, I realize. I'm going to use this format just inside the database. To set up a format  is just a part of my task.

Comment: Again, datetime data is not stored formatted and any calculations are done on the raw data values. Formatting a datetime value should be the last thing you do before presenting it to the end user.

Comment: *I'm going to use this format just inside the database.* No you are not. Inside the database your timestamp will be in an internally defined structure which you have absolutely no control over. Any formatting has just 2 purposes: Display the value and used to convert from an external representation to the internal structure.